# Find duration between touch events in android

Tags: java, android

I have set up an `onTouchListener` which allows the user to click `textView2` exactly 10 times, as shown below. My goal is to measure the time between touch 1 and touch 2, and store it as a variable, say `time1`. However, I'm not quite sure how to do this. One idea I had was setting up a variable, `i`, that measures the number of times the `TouchListener` was clicked. I was thinking of potentially measuring the time that `i` contained a particular value (for example, if `i` was equal to 1 for 1 second, this means the time between touch 1 and touch 2 was 1 second). However I'm not sure how to implement this, and I'm not even sure if this is the correct method. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

`.java` file

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

int i;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final TextView textView2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    i=0;

    textView2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                i++;
                if (i==10) textView2.setOnTouchListener(null);

            }
            return false;
        }
    });         

}
```

Comment: So you want to cap the number of requests possible in a given time?

Comment: @Raffaele no I just want to measure the duration between each touch event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your class

```
private long pressTime = -1l;
private long releaseTime = 1l;
private long duration = -1l;
```

Then in your onTouch method

```
if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
     pressTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
     if(releaseTime != -1l) duration = pressTime - releaseTime;
}
else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
     releaseTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
     duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - pressTime;
}
```

Now you have your duration between touch events:

- Duration when you press down is the time between the last time you released and the current press (if you have previously pressed down and released the button).
- Duration when you release is the time between the last time you pressed down and the current release time.

-Edit-

If you need to know the difference in time of all events you can just do something like

```
private long lastEvent = -1l;
private long duration = -1l;
```

Then in onTouch event

```
if(lastEvent != -1l) duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - lastEvent;
lastEvent = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

You can also create a list of durations

```
private List<Long> durations = new ArrayList<Long>();
```

and in onTouch instead of duration = ... do

```
durations.add(System.currentTimeMillis() - lastEvent);
```

This could be useful for checking all durations between all sequential events. For example, if you want to know the time between pressing down, dragging, stopping dragging, starting dragging, and then lifting up you could check your list after you lift up for every time in question instead of having to constantly check a single duration.

Comment: Cool, do you know how I could adapt it for the 9 different durations? Is it possible to employ 9 duration variables?

Comment: @user3616949 You can either add a variable for each event (like dragTime and stuff) and modify the original code I posted to determine time between desired events (like time between press press down and moving), or you could use something generic like what I added in my edit to perform the action on all events.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to keep a record of events in a `List`. The objects stored in this list would keep the timestamp of the touch event, and since UI events are dispatched by a single thread and the clock is monothonic, you are guaranteed that event at `N + 1` has a later (at most  equal) timestamp than event at index `N`.

I'm not sure about how you clean this list, however. It depends on how and why you read events, which in turn depends on what you want to do with the delay between two subsequent touch.

For example, if you just wanted to display the time since last touch, a simple code like this could be enough:

```
public class MyActivity {

  private int times = 0;
  private long lastTimestamp;

  private void onTouchEvent(Event evt) {
    if (times > 0) {
      long delay = evt.getTimestamp() - lastTimestamp;
      // do something with the delay
    }
    lastTimestamp = evt.getTimestamp();
    times++;
  }
}
```