# Android ontouchlistener counter implementation

Tags: android, multithreading, ontouchlistener

I have set ontouch listener to implement a counter for my imagebutton. But I can only detect button being touched and release. I am not sure how to implement incrementing as long as the button is pressed and how to stop it after it is released. Following is the code I have:

up.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

```
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
       if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        pressdown();
    }
       else if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        pressrelease();
    }
       return true;
    }
```

Comment: Add variables that give duration. Just answered a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23793345/find-duration-between-touch-events-in-android/23793548?noredirect=1#comment36596443_23793548

Comment: Thank you but I am trying to increment a value for the as long as a button is pressed. Not calculate how long it is pressed/released.

Comment: Gotcha, in that case you could start a separate thread with a handler that counts for you in ACTION_DOWN and stop the thread using the handler to work with the incremented value. There are a number of ways to do it but that's one. Sorry I misunderstood your post initially.

Comment: Thanks. I know nothing about threads and handlers. Could you care to direct me to any examples that already implement this or could you give me a pseudo code for this example? If yes, you could 'answer' my question.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Here's a solution to my own question. It might help someone else.

use a Handler object because you have to implement a separate thread for incrementing/decrementing

```
       public class MainActivity extends Activity{

       private boolean autoIncrement = false;
       private boolean autoDecrement = false;
       private final long REPEAT_DELAY = 50;
       private Handler repeatUpdateHandler = new Handler();


       @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.input);


        class RepetitiveUpdater implements Runnable{

         @Override
         public void run() {
         if (autoIncrement) {
         increment();
             repeatUpdateHandler.postDelayed(new RepetitiveUpdater(), REPEAT_DELAY);
        }
         else if(autoDecrement){
         decrement();
             repeatUpdateHandler.postDelayed(new RepetitiveUpdater(), REPEAT_DELAY);
        }
    }

     }
                up.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            increment();
         }
         });

                up.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

          @Override
          public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
          autoIncrement = true;
          repeatUpdateHandler.post(new RepetitiveUpdater());
          return false;
            }
            });

                up.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {                                                          
                   @Override
           public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && autoIncrement ){
                autoIncrement = false;
                     } 
         return false;
          }
        });

               public void increment(){
       if (i<100) {
           i++;
           TextView no = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.no);
       no.setText(String.valueOf(i));
    }

}

    }
```

Do the same for decrement.

Courtesy: Github, author: Jeffrey F. Cole